# On literary techniques

Tags: australian-english, literary-techniques

Are there any literary techniques in these quotes?

> “But a man who comes to power with the support of the common people holds it alone and has no one around him who’s unwilling to obey”

and

> “If he’s begging help, he’s bound to fail and will get nowhere”

They are both from Machiavelli's *The Prince* :)

Answer (score 1):

**These are examples of "aphorism"**

> [**Aphorism**](http://literarydevices.net/aphorism/) is a statement of truth or opinion expressed in a concise and witty manner. The term is often applied to philosophical, moral and literary principles.
>
> To qualify as an aphorism, it is necessary for a statement to contain a truth revealed in a terse manner. Aphoristic statements are quoted in writings as well as in our daily speech. The fact that they contain a truth gives them a universal acceptance. Scores of philosophers, politicians, writers, artists and sportsman and other individuals are remembered for their famous aphoristic statements. see, literarydevices.net